# Recode only certain values keep others as it is while preserving multiple data types in different columns?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with more than 1000 character columns. I want to recode certain character columns as numeric but keep other columns as characters. I hope to achieve this **without** manually including/excluding columns for recoding (aka the operation needs to be on the entire data frame). I tried using dplyr::recode and dplyr::case_when but the unrecoded columns were all coerced into NA or I had to convert all columns into numeric.

A toy dataset:

```
 df = tibble(name = c('Tom', 'Sarah'), wealth = c('poor', 'wealthy'), health = c('poor', 'good'))
```

I think dplyr::recode and dplyr::case require all columns to be the same type after recoding, yet I don't want the 'name' column to be numeric.

I tried using:

```
df_recoded = df %>% mutate(across(everything(),~recode(
  ., 
  'poor' = 1, 
  'good' = 2,
  'wealthy' = 2,
  .default = .    #doesn't work
)))
```

Or

```
 df_recoded = df %>% mutate(across(everything(),~case_when(
      . == 'poor' ~ 1, 
      . == 'good' ~ 2,
      . == 'wealthy' ~ 2, 
      TRUE ~ .    # doesn't work. 
    )))
```

The desired output is:

```
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   name  wealth health
#>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> 
#> 1 Tom   1      1     
#> 2 Sarah 2      2
```

Comment: A somewhat hacky solution - you could convert to character representations of the numbers `"1"` and `"2"`, and then use `type.convert` to convert any pseudo-numeric columns to actual numerics. (But my guess is there's a more direct way...)

Comment: What output you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(name = c('Tom', 'Sarah'), 
            wealth = c('poor', 'wealthy'), 
            health = c('poor', 'good')) 

df %>%  
    mutate(across(everything(), 
                  ~ case_when(.x == "poor" ~ "1", 
                              .x %in% c("good", "wealthy") ~ "2",
                              TRUE ~ .x))) -> df_recoded

df_recoded[] <- lapply(names(df_recoded) , 
\(x) if(x != "name") as.numeric(df_recoded[[x]]) else df_recoded[[x]])
```

you can use `base R` to simplify the solution

```
l <- lapply(df , \(x) ifelse(x == "poor" , 1 , ifelse(x %in% c("good", "wealthy") , 2 , x)))

l$wealth <- as.numeric(l$wealth)
l$health <- as.numeric(l$health)

as_tibble(l)
```

- output

```
df_recoded

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  name  wealth health
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Tom        1      1
2 Sarah      2      2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a simplier way? Or can we make the if_else step more interpretable?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that `1` and `2` needs to be characters when you do this operation.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(name = c('Tom', 'Sarah'), 
            wealth = c('poor', 'wealthy'), 
            health = c('poor', 'good')) 

df %>%  
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                ~ case_when(.x == "poor" ~ "1", 
                                 .x %in% c("good", "wealthy") ~ "2",
                                 TRUE ~ .x)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   name  wealth health
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 Tom   1      1     
#> 2 Sarah 2      2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This solution doesn't fully address the question, as "I want recode certain character columns as **numeric** but keep other columns as characters".